# Building a presentation using different individual slides in sharepoint

Tags: slidelibrary

Has slide library been discontinued in latest release of sharepoint? I would like our users to be able access ppts in sharepoint and then build a presentation using specific slides that could come from a multitude of different presentations?

Answer (score 0):

Slide Library is discontinued from SharePoint 2013.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Discontinued-features-and-modified-functionality-in-Microsoft-SharePoint-2013-bbbb0815-2538-4f1d-b647-1f7f6d508c93?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US#__toc382936212

There is a workaround to make it available in SharePoint 2013 and it will work seamless with Office 2013 - https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/justmeetingsnoactualwork/2016/04/24/sharepoint-2010-slide-libraries-can-be-used-in-sharepoint-2016-at-least-old-ones/

Just a heads up this workaround will not work with Office 2016.

That being said you should start harnessing the co-authoring feature instead.

Comment: pls tell me a little bit more about the co-authoring feature?

Comment: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Document-collaboration-and-co-authoring-ee1509b4-1f6e-401e-b04a-782d26f564a4

Comment: Thank you while it's nice, it's not exactly what I am looking for. I don't want them to be able to co-author but instead I want our presenters to have access to all the presentations in share point where they can view individual slides without downloading. Then if they like a slide or 2 (not the whole presentation) then they can bring that slide or 2 and create an entirely new presentation made up of slides from a number of diff presentations. From reading about Slide library, it would have allowed me to do this.

Comment: Ok in that case you should request ITS to enable slide library in your environment as I have explained in the link. This will be only a temporary fix - once you move to 2016 its gone.. hope there will be another way by that time.